# TYPO3 - dev: Resizing images in custom extension

Tags: typo3

What is the equivalent of this Typoscript in PHP?

```
10 = IMAGE
10.file{
    width = 400
    height = 300
    import = uploads/pics/
    import.field = image
}
```

I'm guessing there is something in TYPO3 libraries that does the same. I have Imagemagick installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pi1 class of your ext:

```
$mediaArray = explode(',', $row['media']);
$imgConf = array();
$imgConf['file'] = 'uploads/media/'.$mediaArray[0];
$imgConf['altText'] = $row['nav_title']?$row['nav_title']:$row['title'];
$imgConf['file.'] = $conf['somePreset.']['file.'];
$image = $this->cObj->IMAGE($imgConf);
```

in TypoScript template:

```
plugin.tx_myext_pi1.somePreset.file {
  maxW = 320
  maxH = 130
}
```

You can also set the dimensions directly in PHP by replacing:

```
$imgConf['file.'] = $conf['somePreset.']['file.'];
```

with inline `array()`:

```
$imgConf['file.'] = array(
  'maxW' => '320',
  'maxH' => '130',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your TYPO3 configuration (in Installer tool). It either uses ImageMagick (or GraphicsMagick) (which are external tools), or GD2 (which is a PHP lib usually included on PHP installation).

To see examples of image resizing, ask Google. There are a lot of examples available.

Comment: So its not part of the tslib? Because I know Typoscript caches the resized images, and I was wondering if I could get the same with tslib.